# Change "Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK."

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Is there a way in one of the Django scripts to change the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>BREAK</kbd> exit command to something else when using `python manage.py runserver` ?

Comment: Do you mean stop the development runserver ?

Comment: @aircraft correct.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ctrl + C worked perfectly on PC

Comment: Yea, I later found out that Ctrl+C was what pc needed. (Even though the console said otherwise) Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ps` and `grep` to find the process:

```
ps aux | grep runserver
```

then kill it by:

```
kill the_pid
```

I mean you can write this to a shell script, then invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

unluckily for me it doesn't work. i tried:
`ctrl + fn + b`
`ctrl + fn + c`
`ctrl + fn + pause(F5)`
`ctrl + c`

neeh help to end my server without re-opening the terminal which is connected to anaconda

Comment: Please explain how your text actually answers the question of OP. As of now, it seems like you are referring to an issue, not an answer.

Comment: I solved it worked the day after inexplicably

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32773470)

Answer (score 0):

On windows 11 type exit() this will return to the Python (venv) virtual environment

to exit the (venv)\scripts\deactivate

and from there you can use the regular commands.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).